# How often vibration is used to indicate item locations?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

Since Switch Lite doesn't have vibration motors, [Nintendo has an alternative for the rumble in a form of visual "screen-shake"](https://reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/d7xneu/the_super_mario_odyssey_rumble_moon_effect_has/) in Odyssey. The indicator is subtle, challenging to notice especially when crossing (a) challenge room tile(s) and have this effect to play for a split second. At least in the context of my eyesight and viewing distance, I can't see obvious motion on the Lite's 5.5-inch display  even when standing on top of a moon.

Comment: I'm quite confident that the screen shake effect hasn't been active on my Switch. I have the latest version of Odyssey at the time of writing. I would capture footage, but an external capture device is needed I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through a list of Power Moons, I found 5 moons where rumble is used to hint at the hidden moon's location.

- Sand Kingdom: (17) Top of a Dune
- Sand Kingdom: (52) A Rumble From The Sandy Floor
- Metro Kingdom: (16) Left at the Cafe?
- Seaside Kingdom: (41) A Rumble on the Seaside Floor
- Bowser's Kingdom (42): A Rumble Under the Arena Floor

Additionally, there are 4 fishing moons that use rumble to indicate when to reel in your line.

- Sand Kingdom: (34) Fishing in the Oasis
- Lake Kingdom: (15) Lake Fishing
- Snow Kingdom: (17) Fishing in the Glacier!
- Bowser's Castle: (27) Fishing(?) in Bowser's Castle

Sources

- [Polygon - Super Mario Odyssey guide: Cap Kingdom all power moon locations](https://www.polygon.com/super-mario-odyssey-guide-walkthrough/2017/11/16/16546034/power-moon-locations-kingdoms)
- [Mario Wiki - Lists of Power Moons](https://www.mariowiki.com/Lists_of_Power_Moons)
- [Reddit: Help: which moons *require* rumble for completing SMO 100%?](https://www.reddit.com/r/SuperMarioOdyssey/comments/9sjybr/help_which_moons_require_rumble_for_completing/)

Comment: Polygon and Mario Wiki, oddly, don't mention "vibration" or "rumble" at all. But as a wiki, the information likely can be added to the latter.

Comment: @user598527 Polygon does mention rumble. I accidentally linked the Cap Kingdom list instead of the all moons page. This has been fixed.